# If password fails, make GDM switch bach to the User list in 5 seconds

Tags: login, gdm

If the user enters an incorrect password on GDM in Ubuntu 20.04, the password box is redisplayed along with the error message, "Sorry that didn't work. Please try again."

1. If you do not enter a password, the password box remains on the screen indefinitely.
2. If you enter the incorrect password three times, GDM automatically switches back to the user list after the third failed attempt.

Is it possible to configure GDM to wait 5 seconds after each failed attempt and automatically switch back to the user list, if the user does not enter a password in the allotted time? (In other words, can behavior #2 above be made the default for all password attempts?)

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: GDM in Ubuntu 20.04